# React select and change the style of link

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink, styles

I have two buttons in my form and I want them to change style when you clicked on them. Currently, they are like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function InstantQuoteForm () {
  return (
    <Form className="shadow p-3 mb-5">
      <Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
        <button type="submit" className="links">
         Button1
        </button>
        <button type="submit" className="links">
          Button2
        </button>
      </Form.Group>
      
    </Form>
  );
}
```

So, when I click one of them I want to add a 'link-selected' style to it. I could do that but I wasn't successful on when I clicked another one, the first one was still with 'link-selected' style. Could you please help me to solve this issue.

```
.links-selected {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--body-color);;
  color: var(--second-color);
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom:  solid var(--first-color);
}
```

Comment: Do you want that link to redirect you to another route?

Comment: Actually I want to change the content of some div according to the selected link

Comment: `Link` doesn't have a prop called `type=submit`. Maybe you mean `input` field.

Comment: I first use buttons then changed them to links. Now, they are fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can do this way. When the button is focused its style is changed.

```
.links-selected:focus {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: var(--body-color);;
  color: var(--second-color);
  padding: 0.75rem 1rem;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-bottom:  solid var(--first-color);
}
```

Also, you can create a state to preserve the id of the clicked button:

```
export default function InstantQuoteForm () {
  const [clickedButtonId, setClickedButtonId] = useState("");
  return (
    <Form className="shadow p-3 mb-5">
      <Form.Group controlId="formGroupFrom">
        <button type="submit" className="links" 
         onClick={()=>setClickedButtonId("btn1")} 
         className={`${clickedButtonId === "btn1" && "links-selected"}`}>
         Button1
        </button>
        <button type="submit" className="links" 
         onClick={()=>setClickedButtonId("btn2")} 
         className={`${clickedButtonId === "btn2" && "links-selected"}`}>
         Button2
        </button>
      </Form.Group>
      
    </Form>
  );
}
```

Also, you need to prevent the form from submitting by passing this handler to the `onSubmit`:

```
const handleSubmit = (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately didn't work well. It refreshed the page and turned back to the previous style.

Comment: Thansk it worked just like I want but I did a change which is not important but I wanted to mention: <button type="submit"
         onClick={()=>setClickedButtonId("btn1")} 
         className={`links ${clickedButtonId === "btn1" && "links-selected"}`}>
         Button1
        </button> So I changed this part a little bit. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Very new to CSS, but I believe you need a sudo selector, which would look something like this:

```
.links_selected:visited { }
```

Otherwise your CSS won't know when to apply this specific thing. Feel free to correct me if I made an erro.